# Property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to run an MVC unit test on an action that clones a record. Naturally, we use the master record's primary key to pull it from the database first using a simple `DbSet.Find()`. Right now I have about 100 unit tests written, and 98/100 are passing including a number of which are required to test various aspects of this type of transaction... and they're all passing.

In the first step a user has chosen to create an `Agency` but selected that they also would like to add another. The page will post back to the `Create` `POST` controller method and save.

Once the save is complete, the program is design to re-route back to the `Create` `GET` method. From there it gathers the relevant information and posts the new model object back to the view.

```
var result = _controlAgtTran.Create(_agency, "andAddAnother") as RedirectToRouteResult;
var message = _controlAgtTran.Create(int.Parse(result.RouteValues["id"].ToString()), null, null, null, null, null, true, result.RouteValues["msg"].ToString()) as ViewResult;
```

Nothing too complicated happens once we're re-routed to the `GET` action, as you can see below. We simply call a `DbSet.Find(<PK>)` method to grab the object we just saved.

```
AgentTransmission master = db.AgentTransmission.Find(id);
```

However, each and every time, and for this operation alone, I the following error message. I've stepped through the code to make sure the `id` variable is not null, I've queried the database to make sure it's correct, and I've compared this portion of the unit test to others in the solution and can't find a difference. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: A find doesn't modify anything... that error would only occur when changes are saved.

Comment: I know... that's why I'm so confused. Most of everything I've read online involves scenarios where someone is trying to do an update. I'm simply pulling information from the database. Screen shot attached to the post, btw.

Comment: Visual Studio's debug information can sometimes be confused.. Sometimes the actual error is on a statement before or after, or maybe your debug information is out of date and you need to clean your project and do a complete rebuild.

Comment: It might be possible that `DetectChanges` that is called internally by `Find` before the actual DB query runs is causing the exception. You could test it by just calling `db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` before your `Find` call. If it throws the exception it indicates that you have modified the key property of some attached object somewhere *before* you are calling `Find`.

Comment: I faced a similar issue today where the exception was thrown on a Find() which basically does not modify anything! I found that I was iterating and updating a different object using the same DBContext in an earlier function to read data from the same collection.  The fix was to create a new DBContext variable and use it for the Find().

Comment: I've also just ran into this issue

Comment: Well? https://xkcd.com/979/ comes to mind.. Colleague of mine had a similar issue, just put a private setter on his ID attributes of his entites..

Comment: I tried Mardoxx's idea and it worked, but I had to undo it because of other consequences that caused.

Comment: Wish I could upvote TwoPea a hundred times. That is exactly what I spent 4 hours trying to figure out. I was trying to duplicate a record by using `context.model.Where()` to pull it then use that object to do `context.model.Add(freshlypulledobject)`. It was throwing this error until I used a new instance of the context to do the `Add()`.